# How to import images through csv?

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, importexport, dataflow

I have uploaded 2000 simple products through csv just now.
But i didnt include images. 
How we can upload images at a time through csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upload images in `media/import` folder and the image name in respective field in csv.

Comment: Okay. so, i have to mension the sku and name also in csv?

Comment: only sku if updating existing product. SKU is the key to associate data to product. Put small_image, thumbnail and base_image in CSV.

Comment: okay Credevator

Comment: put same image name in media_image field as well, you can add multiple images by putting in media_image in separate rows.